# A difficult integral: $\int_0^{+\infty} e^{ - x}\left(\frac1{x( e^{ - x} - 1 )} + \frac1{x^2} + \frac1{2x} \right) \, dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, closed-form

Could you help me calculate the integral?

> $$\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-x} \left(\frac1{x(e^{-x}-1)} + \frac1{x^2} + \frac1{2x} \right) \, dx .$$

Comment: Hint. The desired value is $\frac12 \ln (2\pi)-1$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Could you show me the detail?

Comment: That's an amazing answer. I am certainly interested in the work. Could it be done with Laplace? Would you have to make a common denominator?

Comment: Writing {{{x^2+1}}} where {x^2+1} or x^2+1 will suffice, writing {{e^{-1}}+1} where e^{-x}+1 will suffice, etc., neither makes editing easier nor is conducive to those (who do seem to exist) who get their ideas of how to write LaTeX code from this site.  I surmise that you're using some kind of software to write the code rather than doing it by hand.  That's the usual explanation of why it looks as if a lunatic wrote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One may recall [Binet's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsLogGammaFormulas.html), for $\Re z >0$,
$$
\log \Gamma(z)= \left( z-\frac{1}{2}\right)\log z - z + \frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi) + 
\int_0^{\infty} \!
\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{e^{x}-1} \right)\frac{e^{-zx}}{x} \mathrm{d}x. \tag1
$$ Observing  that
$$
{\left( {\frac{1}{{x\left( {{e^{ - x}} - 1} \right)}} + \frac{1}{{{x^2}}} + \frac{1}{{2x}}} \right)} =-\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{e^{x}-1} \right)\frac{1}{x}
$$ then, using $(1)$ with $z:=1$, readily gives

> $$
> \int_0^{ + \infty } {{e^{ - x}}\left( {\frac{1}{{x\left( {{e^{ - x}} - 1} \right)}} + \frac{1}{{{x^2}}} + \frac{1}{{2x}}} \right)dx}= \frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi)-1.
> $$